# Spinner, ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have a problem with the Spinner. I have set the ArrayAdapter and set OnItemSelected Listener. but in the onClick method it shows an error in the els-if statement an error.

```
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.category_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        categorySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.editCategorySpinner);

        categorySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        categorySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}

private void configureButton2() {
        Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSave);

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (textName.getText().length() == 0) {
                    textName.requestFocus();
                    return;
                } else if (textContent.getText().length() == 0) {
                    textContent.requestFocus();
                    return;
                } else if (categorySpinner.**getText**().length() == 0) {
                    CategorySpinner.requestFocus();
                    return;
                } else {
                    //next Step: get the mood
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity2.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("textName", textName.getText().toString());
                myIntent.putExtra("textContent", textContent.**getText**().toString());
                myIntent.putExtra("CategorySpinner", CategorySpinner.**getText()**.toString());
                v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
            }
                }
            }
        });
        }

@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {

        String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

I tried this in the else-if statement:

```
} else if (((CharSequence) docuCategory.getTag()).length() == 0) {
                docuCategory.requestFocus();
                return;
```

this dose not show any error but the emulator "unfortunately stopped"

Hope you can help me.

Comment: What error you see with the `else if` ?

Comment: else if (categorySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition == 0)

Comment: getSelectedItemPosition cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: May be because you are calling `requestFocus();` with the class name `CategorySpinner` instead of the object `categorySpinner` ?

Comment: categorySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0, that is right thanks, but what should I do here : myIntent.putExtra("categorySpinner", categorySpinner.getText().toString());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to use `getSelectedItemPosition` method to get the position of selected item. Selected item position will be passed to `onItemSelected` method as a parameter. In your case variable name **pos** will be the selected item position.

Try this.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {

    int selectedPosition = pos;

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: it shows anyway error in: myIntent.putExtra("categorySpinner", categorySpinner.**getText()**.toString());

Comment: ok I got it :) I set this: categorySpinner.getContext().toString()